# Finding Growth Rate using Newton's Method

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I am a bit perplexed by this problem. I am given an equation of:

$1564=1000e^\lambda + \frac{435}{\lambda}(e^\lambda-1)$

where $\lambda_{0}=1$

The question asks to perform Newtons method once to find an approximation of $\lambda_{1}$. Here is where I am having trouble, I can easily calculate the value of $\lambda$ using calculus but the equation above represents population growth. I can easily solve for population using newtons method but not the constant, $\lambda$. How would you actually solve this then?

Comment: What's $\lambda_0$? What's $\lambda_1$?

Comment: Lambda represents rate of birth.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to just do it.

```
decimal.getcontext().prec=40
x=decimal.Decimal(1)

for k in range(8):
    ex = x.exp()
    f  = 1000*ex+435*(ex-1)/x-1564
    df = 1000*ex+435*ex/x-435*(ex-1)/x**2
    print "%2d %44s %44s"%(k,x,f)
    x = x - f/df
```

to get the iteration sequence

```
k   x                                             f(x)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                                            1    1901.734423838729912742012521391070684281
1   0.3969031227481259043430888746827019616688     457.188882021901362149278051953610760865
2   0.1388690005458458374348832095249271495320      51.625635605039106407222909186487362447
3   0.1016666484810883840629040924898754077344       0.895689482788235733248531107570043312
4   0.1009981404995350112100984626739410398824       0.000282277360385651673393235168548724
5   0.1009979296857707443564783409084902454646              2.8059058649170931631933147E-11
6   0.1009979296857497889495568910380408930097                            2.77247289341E-25
7   0.1009979296857497889495568908309837055733                                        0E-36
```

As you can see, the first iterate is still somewhat off in function value and relative to the result. One might also try to reformulate the equation in fixed point form by solving for the argument inside the exponential and then use Aitken's method as variant of Newton's method,...